# User with admin right is not able to claim or complete another user's task in jbpm

Tags: jboss, jbpm, bpmn

I have a user ABC with roles - admin,process-admin,user,kie-server,analyst,manager
When i assign a task to CDE user that has only user right.
Here Admin ABC is not able complete CDE's task.
I am using business central for jbpm workflow deployments.I have used postgreSQL as database.
Can anyone help here what role i am missing or process ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different user than "admin" as this one is treated in a special way by the human task service.

Comment: Sorry to I am not using admin as a user.I have given admin rights to ABC user.But still ABC is not able claim CDE's task even he is admin.

Comment: well, sorry, I think I misunderstood your problem, can you provide more details, I mean about what roles are assigned to that user

Comment: Np.CDE is user with user,kie-server,rest-all roles.ABC is admin user with kie- server,admin,rest-all,process-admin,rest- project,user,manager,developer,owner,Administrator roles.Stil ABC is not able to claim/start/complete CDE's task even being a admin.I also tried org.kie.server.bypass.auth.user=true in standalone.xml file,but that even not working.I dont know what i am missing here.With admin rights he should be able to do it .isn't it ?

Comment: note that he should be assigned to the group "Administrators"

Comment: Assigning user to Administrators group means "case-role-assignmnet":{"role":"group"}. Is it ? or can you explain how do i map group to user or role ?

Comment: Because i am using database to authenticate users, I am using Users and Userroles table for addig user and user roles.Do i have to add group in ORganization Entity table ? if yes  then do i have to map group to user at case creation time like   "case-group-assignments" : { "admin":"BusinessAdministrator"} ? But that is not working too. Is anything i am missing here ?

Comment: can anyone please help here

Comment: try to ask [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!forum/jbpm-usage) , the community there  is more active than on stackoverflow